# How complete a string without exceed a determinated limit?

Tags: javascript

I have a sequence of 47 numbers, where i must complete with 0 (zeros) to right if lenght is lower that 47.

```
var numbers = "42297115040000195441160020034520268610000054659";
var numbers_lenght = numbers.length;

if (numbers_lenght < 47)
    numbers = numbers.concat("0");

    alert(numbers);
```

But i want know of a way where the complement not exceed to > 47 independent of lenght < 47 is the string.

How make this?

Comment: Is your `alert` deliberately outside of your `if` statement?

Comment: @Brandon, Yes, this is the code.

Comment: `numbers = numbers.padEnd(47, '0');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern browsers, you can use [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) here:

> The padEnd() method pads the current string with a given string (repeated, if needed) so that the resulting string reaches a given length. The padding is applied from the end (right) of the current string.

```js
var numbers = "54321";
const result = numbers.padEnd(47, '0')
console.log(result + ' :: ' + result.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to just concatenate 1 `0` you want to add `47 - string_length` zeros, right? You can use [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for that:

```js
var numbers = "123456789123";
var numbers_length = numbers.length;
if (numbers_length < 47) {
    numbers = numbers.concat('0'.repeat(47 - numbers_length)) 
}
console.log(numbers)
console.log("length: ", numbers.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.  You're on the right track.  You are concatenating `"0"` to pad.  What you are missing is the repetition.

There are a few ways to solve this.  Since you seem to be learning, I'll start with the brute force approach to make sure you understand how it all works.

```
var numbers = "42297115040000195441160020034520268610000054659";
while (numbers.length < 47) {
    numbers = numbers.concat("0");
}
alert(numbers);
```

All I did was change your `if` to `while`.

That said, there are methods built in to JavaScript which can do this for you.

```
var numbers = "42297115040000195441160020034520268610000054659";
numbers += "0".repeat(47 - numbers.length);
```

Even more expressive:

```
var numbers = "42297115040000195441160020034520268610000054659";
numbers = numbers.padEnd(47, "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can accomplish what you're trying to do if you just stick your logic inside a `while` loop:

```js
var number1 = "42297115040000195441160020034520268610000054659";
var number2 = "4229711504000019";

console.log(padString(number1, 47, "0"));
console.log(padString(number2, 47, "0"));

function padString(str, minimumLength, paddingCharacter) {
  while (str.length < minimumLength) {
    str = str.concat(paddingCharacter);
  }

  return str;
}
```